# swagger - how to set security properly

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

Two questions:

1. When you define a new route and you want to protect it by requiring an api_key to be set in the header, do you do it by specifying a `security` section under that route in the yaml file, or do you put it under `parameters` (or in both)? If it works by putting it under `parameters`, what's the point of putting it under `security`?
2. The yaml file can tell you that certain routes are protected by an api_key, but it doesn't specify the value of that key (as far as I know). Does it mean I need the write some custom middleware that intercepts my routes and checks the validity of the key, or it can be auto-generated by one of the swagger tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im currently on the same journey as you.  I do know this:

- What to add in my swagger.json to accept api key
  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityRequirementObject

  "security": [
  {
    "api_key": []
   }
  ]
- what to add in my controller ...
  https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/docs/Middleware.md

Pretty much use swagger-tools to use the middleware.swaggerSecurity.

- What they dont tell you is how to validate the api_key

Well I found that it's simply taking the 'scopes' parameter which holds the actual key and comparing that against a list of valid keys that you have stored somewhere.

What I dont get is how to allow the flow to go to the next function (like 'next()' in express) or stop if there is an invalid API key supplied.  There is a 'callback' parameter, but I dont know how to use it (yet).

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to implement the security checks on your own.  Swagger will help you define them, but implementing is your job.

Comment: can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434335/why-is-swagger-security-definitions-not-working